# How to align integers on the right, but still center them

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

Suppose we have a table like this:

```
\begin{tabular}{c}
Heading \\
1 \\
10 \\
100 \\
\end{tabular}
```

This will center all the numbers. If I want to align them to the right, I could change the column definition to `r`, but that would but the numbers on the right end of the table. What I would like is for the widest number (in this case `100`) to be centered with respect to the column, and the others to be right-aligned to that number. There seem to be [a](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/rccol.html) [bajillion](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/dcolumn.html) [packages](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/siunitx.html) out there that deal in one way or another with aligning numbers by their decimal points, but none seem to offer a simple way to pad numbers to a fixed width. Does anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Using [`siunitx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) you'd do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{S[table-format=3.0]}
\toprule
{Heading} \\
\midrule
1 \\
10 \\
100 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I get the error `table-format undefined in families key`.

Comment: maybe you need to update your system to get the newest siunitx?

Comment: @Space: It works correctly for me. Maybe you have an old version of `siunitx`.

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y. I've used the settings appropriate for v2 of `siunitx`. If you have version 1 (which sounds likely)  replace `table-format` by `tabformat` and use `\multicolumn` for the heading.

Comment: @Juan: You were right, I was still running Tex Live 2009. After updating, it works like a charm.

Answer (score 6):

If you want it less complicated then use the `\makebox` directly for the numbers
and `\multicolumn` for the header.

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{array,calc}

\newcolumntype{C}{>{\FormatNo} c }
\def\FormatNo\ignorespaces#1\\{%
  \ignorespaces\makebox[\widthof{000}][r]{#1}\tabularnewline}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{C}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Heading} \\
1 \\
10 \\
100 \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just to be picky: `\ignorespaces` in the replacement text of the `\FormatNo` macro does nothing (apart expanding `\makebox`; its place should be before `#1`.

Answer (score 0):

The process can be somewhat automated using [`eqparbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/eqparbox)'s `\eqmakebox[<tag>][<align>]{<stuff>}` and the help of [`collcell`](//ctan.org/pkg/collcell) to `coll`ect the contents - `<stuff>` of each `cell` and pass that to `\eqmakebox`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{eqparbox,collcell}

\newcommand{\columnalign}{}
\newcommand{\columnalignment}[2]{\renewcommand{\columnalign}{\eqmakebox[#1][#2]}}

\begin{document}

\columnalignment{tag1}{r}

\begin{tabular}{>{\collectcell\columnalign}c<{\endcollectcell}}
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{Heading} \\
  1000 \\
     1 \\
    10 \\
   100
\end{tabular}

\columnalignment{tag2}{r}

\begin{tabular}{>{\collectcell\columnalign}c<{\endcollectcell}}
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{Heading} \\
       words \\
          of \\
   differing \\
      length
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Note that this requires at least two compilations with every change in the largest element associated with any specific `<tag>`.

Answer (score -2):

There is no need to use a special LaTeX package. You can use the following standard LaTeX construction with an @-expression:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{r@{\ \ \ \ \ }}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Heading} \\
1 \\
10 \\
100 \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The drawback is that you need to fiddle with the number of spaces you add to the @-expression.

Comment: This is very tedious, needs controlling every time the table, the font or even `\tabcolsep` is changed and only allows approximate centering. All in all, this doesn't really seem like a (viable) solution.