# Right-centered columns in LyX

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, lyx, siunitx

This is very near to my topic: [How to align integers on the right, but still center them](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9203/how-to-align-integers-on-the-right-but-still-center-them).
However, I do not get it to work under LyX. This is the code I have:

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}\caption{\textbf{\label{tab:uebersicht-alle-mspatienten}Untersuchungsergebnisse der soziodemographischen und neurologischen Parameter aller untersuchten MS-Patienten} }
\begin{tabular}{>{\raggedright}p{0.35\columnwidth}>{\centering}p{0.1\columnwidth}>{\centering}p{0.1\columnwidth}>{\centering}p{0.1\columnwidth}>{\centering}p{0.1\columnwidth}}
\toprule 
 & \textbf{Anzahl (n)} & \textbf{Prozent} & \textbf{Mittelwert} & \textbf{SD}\tabularnewline
\midrule
\midrule 
\textbf{Patienten} & 180 &  &  & \tabularnewline
\midrule 
\textbf{Alter} (in Jahren) &  &  & 43,9 & 13,1\tabularnewline
\midrule 
\textbf{Geschlecht:}
- Weiblich
- Männlich & ~
125
55 & ~
69,4
30,6 &  & \tabularnewline
\midrule 
\textbf{Erkrankungsdauer der MS}
(in Jahren) &  &  & 12,3 & 8,8\tabularnewline
\midrule 
\textbf{Verlaufsform:}
- RRMS
- SCP
- PPMS
- CIS & ~
86
67
24
3 & ~
47,8
37,2
13,3
1,7  &  & \tabularnewline
\midrule 
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
```

It produces the following (correct) output:

[image]

However, if I change the first line to:

```
\begin{tabular}{>{\raggedright}p{0.35\columnwidth}S[table-format=3.0]>{\centering}p{0.1\columnwidth}>{\centering}p{0.1\columnwidth}>{\centering}p{0.1\columnwidth}}
```

it gives the following (incorrect) output:

[image]

My version of `siunitx` is `2.2i (2011/06/15)` from TeX Live 2011.

Comment: You need to remove the braces (grouping) around your `S[table-format=3.0]` column definition.

Comment: Like so? Then I get even more errors (all illegal pream-token): \begin{tabular}{>{\raggedright}p{0.35\columnwidth}S[table-format=3.0]>{\centering}p{0.1\columnwidth}>{\centering}p{0.1\columnwidth}>{\centering}p{0.1\columnwidth}}

Comment: Sorry, I had commented out the usepackage command, now the doc. compiles fine.

Comment: Yes. Did you include the `siunitx` package? If so, what version do you have (add `\listfiles` before `\documentclass` and view the contents of your `.log` file after `**File List**`)? The [most recent version on CTAN](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) is `2011/12/11 v2.4e`.

Comment: For completeness, since it seemed to have solved your problem, I've converted my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The elements contained within the column specification of a `tabular` environment should be considered similar to single-letter commands that may take parameters. For example, `S[<key-value list>]` denotes an `S` column with parameters set according to the (optional) `<key-value list>`. Wrapping this in braces

```
\begin{tabular}{...{S[table-format=3.0]}...}
```

confuses LaTeX. Removing the braces should fix your problem:

```
\begin{tabular}{...S[table-format=3.0]...}
```

Also remember to include the [`siunitx` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx), since it defines the `S` column type.

---

Here is a minimal example of your input producing the correct layout when using `siunitx`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx
\usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs
\usepackage{threeparttable}% http://ctan.org/pkg/threeparttable
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
  \centering
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{\textbf{\label{tab:uebersicht-alle-mspatienten}Untersuchungsergebnisse der soziodemographischen 
      und neurologischen Parameter aller untersuchten MS-Patienten}}
%    \begin{tabular}{>{\raggedright}p{0.35\columnwidth}
%        >{\centering}p{0.1\columnwidth}
%        >{\centering}p{0.1\columnwidth}
%        >{\centering}p{0.1\columnwidth}
%        >{\centering}p{0.1\columnwidth}}
    \begin{tabular}{>{\raggedright}p{0.35\columnwidth}
        S[table-format=3.0]
        >{\centering}p{0.1\columnwidth}
        >{\centering}p{0.1\columnwidth}
        >{\centering}p{0.1\columnwidth}}
      \toprule 
      & \textbf{Anzahl (n)} & \textbf{Prozent} & \textbf{Mittelwert} & \textbf{SD}\tabularnewline
      \midrule
      \midrule 
      \textbf{Patienten} & 180 &  &  & \tabularnewline
      \midrule 
      \textbf{Alter} (in Jahren) &  &  & 43,9 & 13,1\tabularnewline
      \midrule 
      \textbf{Geschlecht:} \tabularnewline
      - Weiblich & 125 & 69,4 & & \tabularnewline
      - M\"{a}nnlich & 55 & 30,6 &  & \tabularnewline
      \midrule
      \textbf{Erkrankungsdauer der MS}
      (in Jahren) &  &  & 12,3 & 8,8 \tabularnewline
      \midrule
      \textbf{Verlaufsform:} \tabularnewline
      - RRMS & 86 & 47,8 \tabularnewline
      - SCP & 67 & 37,2 \tabularnewline
      - PPMS & 24 & 13,3 \tabularnewline
      - CIS & 3 & 1,7 &  & \tabularnewline
      \midrule 
    \end{tabular}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

TeX constructs a table (`tabular`) on a row-by-row basis. It seems like your code (at least what is given in your code snippet) doesn't allow for this row-by-row construction. Specifically, as an example,

```
\textbf{Verlaufsform:}
- RRMS
- SCP
- PPMS
- CIS & ~
86
67
24
3 & ~
47,8
37,2
13,3
1,7  &  & \tabularnewline
```

needs to be modified to read

```
\textbf{Verlaufsform:} \tabularnewline
- RRMS & 86 & 47,8 \tabularnewline
- SCP & 67 & 37,2 \tabularnewline
- PPMS & 24 & 13,3 \tabularnewline
- CIS & 3 & 1,7 &  & \tabularnewline
```

otherwise all the entries that seems like it should be processed in the same column (underneath one another) will end up in the same column on a single row. TeX's output will not match your code layout as input - you need to explicitly say where the columns are separated (using `&`), just like you explicitly state where the row ends (using `\\` or `\tabularnewline`).

Comment: Unfortunately, it now looks like ![this](http://s7.directupload.net/images/111219/iz4auo78.png) instead of ![this](http://s1.directupload.net/images/111219/3ryn4p5o.png)
Is there sth. I'm missing ?

Comment: @Jan: Please add the entire code you have that generates the output you included to your original post via an `edit`, as well as the images. As a new user without image posting privileges simply include the image as normal and remove the `!` in front of it to turn it into a link. Someone with editing privileges will embed the link for you. That way we can assess what the problem is. Also include your version of the [`siunitx` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx).

Comment: Although I know to say thank you by clicking the arrow, I wanted to do it the old way ;-) Btw Lyx produced this code. I inserted another lines (like you suggested) and now it works.

Comment: @Jan: You're welcome! I think LyX sometimes removes the intricacies of (La)TeX coding from the inexperienced user in order to make a little more WYSIWYM (or WYSIWYG). However, this can obscure problems.

Comment: @Jan: How did you do this in LyX? Did you write the whole table in a *raw* block, or is it possible to somehow use the table editor in combination with the siunitx package's `S` column type?

Comment: The topic is rather old and I haven't touched the code ever since. Anyway, it is possible to use the table editor in Lyx and insert the S in the UI. I haven`t used a raw block whatsoever but wanted to come as far as possible in "plain" Lyx.